# android playback suddenly stopping

Tags: android, media, pcm, playback

I have an app that is streaming audio content and sometimes it just
stops all of the suddent.

the logcat windows shows --

AudioHardware pcm playback is going to standby

and that's it.

I saw on another thread (pun intended) that someone was saying it was
because he was using too many threads.  Could that really be causing
this?  Could i give the audio thread higher priority?

Anyway to prevent the audio hardware pcm from going to standby?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same. I don't know what causes it.

Answer (score 2):

I too am having this problem, and have nearly exhausted all my resources trying to find a workaround.  I found an article on how to prevent this with AudioRecord, and maybe the same principles he talks about there will apply to you as well:

http://hificorder.blogspot.com/

In my case, I am having lockups using SoundPool.  Increasing the number of max streams allowed prevented this from happening in most cases, but it still happens in other situations.  I really wish there was better information about how to handled this correctly, because as it is, this is a show stopping bug in my app which may force me to abandon it all together.

Be sure to post back if you have any findings to add.